# inject date string as srtotime

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to resolve this since hours, and I tried different solutions offered here within  the website, but for some reasons the website always returns an error when applying the suggestions.

I have a form field which uses a datepicker, and the output is a date in the format: November 6th, 2013

Now, the mysql database and the rest of the script only works with a ten digit date format, which I have been told is the unix timestamp format and that it can be converted using the strtotime. So I am trying to convert the string into strtotime, but cant resolve this. For now I have:

```
    $insertData['enddate']  = $this->input->post('openDays');
```

which returns the date "November 6th, 2013" and I changed it to

```
  $insertData['enddate'] = strtotime $this->input->post('openDays');
```

which returns the error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/xxx/public_html/app/controllers/project.php on line 214

any suggestions on how to correctly apply this?

Thanks

Comment: Wow. You wasted hours on something this dumb instead of just reading the manual? I hope you learned a lesson to actually look things up for yourself

Comment: lol I am new to this entire programming section :)

Answer (score 1):

**`strtotime`** is a function , so you need to enclose it like this (using parenthesis)

```
$insertData['enddate'] = strtotime($this->input->post('openDays'));
                           -------^                       -------^
```

**EDIT :**

I suggest you use **`DateTime`** instead of **`strtotime`**

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', '17:00');
$insertData['enddate']=$dt->format('H:i');
```

Comment: that worked, cant believe that it was something that simple lol Thanks so much for your quick help

Comment: would you by any chance also know how I can add the option to show the time 5pm by default? currently it is 0:00h

Comment: would it then be $insertData['enddate'] = strtotime('5:00',($this->input->post('openDays'))); ? And if yes, is this 5 am or pm?

Comment: when using 
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', '17:00');
$insertData['enddate']=$dt->format('H:i');
it returns the final vale 01-Jan-1970 00:00h

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you are doing a mistake by using strtotime.

```
$insertData['enddate'] = strtotime($this->input->post('openDays'));
```

Reference link: [Strtotime PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)